# Правильно ли здесь поставлена запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Немалая часть разработок ЦКБА — это наукоемкие, высокотехнологичные в своей области изделия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это однородные определения, раскрывающие общую ему (=изготавливаемые по передовым технологиям), запятая ставится.

НАУКОЁМКИЙ - реализующий передовые научные достижения, ВЫСОКОТЕХНОЛОГИЧНЫЙ - связанный с использованием сложных технологий.